# How can I use an external library with Embedded JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

Suppose I have a very simple lib.js

```
'use strict';

function getCommentText(numComments) {
    var text = " comment";
    if (1 == numComments) return numComments + text
    else return numComments + text + "s";
}
```

I include it in head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/lib.js"></script>
```

In my template I try something like the following

```
<%= getCommentText(3) %>
```

But I get an error message

```
53| var comment = post.comments[i]; getCommentText is not defined
48|
49|
>> 50|
<%= getCommentText(post.comments.length) %>
```

Comment: Can you edit in the error please?

Comment: Can you do an `if/else` like that?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance with templates, but are you trying to execute a JavaScript function with ASP.NET? The code executing getCommentText doesn't look like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<%= 
  <script>
    getCommentText(3)
  </script>
 %>
```

But anyway, if you trying to compute a value and then print it on the screen I recommend you to use `document.write` or setting the text of an attribute with the computed result. Of course, attaching this code to an event (like, get the comments when the user scrolls the page) would be better.